# Xamarin.Android - App Center FirebaseInstanceId.get_Instance Error

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

My Xamarin.Android app Crashes after the user opens up the app, I beleive it has something to do with Firebase but I have not been able to figure it out. Can you please let me know if you have any suggestions on how to fix this error?

FirebaseInstanceId.get_Instance ()
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process "App Name" Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args)
JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters)
FirebaseInstanceId.get_Instance ()
NewUpdateActivity.RunRegistration (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] categories)
AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__7_1 (System.Object state)

Comment: The error message is quite explicit: `Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process "App Name" Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.` Did you call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)`? If you think you did, edit your question to include the [minimum code with which any of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as it's full of useful information on to how to make it most likely that someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your **google-services.json** File build Action is **GoogleServiceJson** if it doesn't work try to initialize your Firebase by yourself in onCreate method before calling any Firebase code.

Here is the manual configuration of Firebase.

```
var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .SetApplicationId("<AppID>")
  .SetApiKey("<ApiKey>")
  .SetDatabaseUrl("<DBURl>")
  .SetStorageBucket("<StorageBucket>")
  .SetGcmSenderId("<SenderID>").Build();
  var fapp = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this, options);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Muhammad Adeel Shoukat, my google-services.json file build Action is set to GoogleServicesJson. Should I enter this piece of code at the bottom of my onCreate Method in my MainActivity.cs File?

Comment: @Nantourakis Glad to hear your issue has bee solved. Don't forget to accept answers which meet your requirements.